# How would I translate this array mapping transformation to SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping, sequence, transformation

Let's say I have the following rows:

```
const rows = [
  { contract: "HC003", type: "Regular" },
  { contract: "HC005", type: "NOT-Regular" },
  { contract: "HC006", type: "NOT-Regular" },
  { contract: "HC007", type: "NOT-Regular" },
  { contract: "HC008", type: "Regular" },
  { contract: "HC015", type: "NOT-Regular" },
  { contract: "HC016", type: "Regular" }
];
```

Each row needs to have a `group`-column added. This column gets the value of the `contract` value of the last row of the *preceding* rows (which means order is significant) where `type` equals `Regular`.

In JS, I would express this along these lines:

```
const findLastRegularContract = rangeEnd =>
  rows
    .slice(0, rangeEnd)
    .reverse()
    .find(row => row.type === "Regular");

const withGroups = rows.map((row, i) => ({
  ...row,
  group: findLastRegularContract(i + 1).contract
}));
```

This leads to the following result:

```
[
  { contract: "HC003", type: "Regular", group: "HC003" },
  { contract: "HC005", type: "NOT-Regular", group: "HC003" },
  { contract: "HC006", type: "NOT-Regular", group: "HC003" },
  { contract: "HC007", type: "NOT-Regular", group: "HC003" },
  { contract: "HC008", type: "Regular", group: "HC008" },
  { contract: "HC015", type: "NOT-Regular", group: "HC008" },
  { contract: "HC016", type: "Regular", group: "HC016" }
]
```

**How would I perform this data transformation in an SQL query?** Is there a way to "map" over rows in SQL? Or is there a declarative / idiomatic way to achieve the same result?

Edit: there are two additional columns which can help with maintaining appropriate sorting, namely:

- `valid from`
- `valid to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extension to your original question is key to the correct answer, since a solution relies on correct ordering of rows.

This can be performed in a declarative fashion, an example of which is the following query (renamed a few columns):

```sql
SELECT  
    a.contract_id, a.contract_type, a.valid_from, a.valid_to,   
    contract_group = 
        (SELECT TOP 1
            contract_id
        FROM 
            contracts b
        WHERE
             b.valid_from <= a.valid_from AND b.contract_type = "Regular"
        ORDER BY b.valid_from DESC)
FROM
    contracts a
ORDER BY
    a.valid_from ASC
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, that's a neat and interesting solution. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a case when

```
 select  case 
          when contract =  "HC003" then  "Regular" 
          when contract =  "HC003" then  "NOT-Regular"
          when contract =  "HC006" then  "NOT-Regular" 
          when contract =  "HC007" then  "NOT-Regular"
          when contract =  "HC008" then  "Regular"
          when contract =  "HC015" then  "NOT-Regular" 
          when contract =  "HC016" then  "Regular"  
        end type          

     , case
          when contract =  "HC003" then  "HC003" 
          when contract =  "HC003" then  "HC003"
          when contract =  "HC006" then  "HC003" 
          when contract =  "HC007" then  "HC003"
          when contract =  "HC008" then  "HC008"
          when contract =  "HC015" then  "HC008" 
          when contract =  "HC016" then  "HC008"  
        end group  
from my_table
```

or you can store the value in corresponding column of  a table and join  ..

my_table

```
   id   contract    type        group 
   1    "HC003"   "Regular"       "HC003" 
   2    "HC005"   "NOT-Regular"   "HC003" 
   3    "HC006"   "NOT-Regular"   "HC003" 
   4    "HC007"   "NOT-Regular"   "HC003" 
   5    "HC008"   "Regular"       "HC008" 
   6    "HC015"   "NOT-Regular"   "HC008" 
   7    "HC016"   "Regular"       "HC016"
```